# What does it mean to access a WMS using a proxy?

Tags: wms, proxy

I am trying to access a WMS service and bring it in through ArcMap, and was given instructions on how to access it using a proxy. Using the proxy script I'm able to download a layer directly to my snapshot. However I don't really understand what it works, and how one gets from that step to using a proxy with ArcGIS so that ArcMap can bring in WMS layers. I have tried searching but I am not exactly understanding what the proxy does and how it is incorporated into a map service/online map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proxy is often used to pass credentials with a request when using token based security.  Typically how this works, at least how I understand it is that you send your request to the proxy, the proxy routine will work on the back end to obtain a token and forward the original request with the token added to the query parameters to the request against the REST Endpoint.  The response is then returned to the client.

If you are doing this you can use a web debugger such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), which will allow you to see the difference in the web requests.  Using the proxy adds an extra layer of security so the client cannot view the access token for the service.  If not using a proxy you can see a token being passed either in cookies (`AGSTOKEN`) or in the query string parameters.

This [page](https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/working-with-proxies/) will explain it better than I can.

Comment: Thanks. This answer was helpful because although I understood the concept of a proxy I didn't understand how it was used with WMS services

Answer (score 2):

Typically we use proxies to appear to be someone else or somewhere else.

As a regular internet user connecting to a server, very little is known about me (IP, rough location, browser details, etc...) by the server. It has little reason to provide information which is meant to be restricted to certain users. Using this limited information however, IP address specifically, a data provider can provide content for certain IP addresses. So a WMS for example may only want government and universities to have access. The IP addresses of those government and university networks are added to the WMS server, to allow a connection.

Now if I am at home and want to access the WMS it's not possible as my home IP is not on the list of accepted IP addresses. What I need to do is connect to the university (or government) and access the WMS through them. The WMS server then sees me as having the university IP.

Many people use proxies to pretend to be in a different country to access services restricted to that country (such as watching Hulu, or US Netflix, or buying a device in another country's online store). Proxies can also used to hide who you are, so if someone wants to download music, videos etc..., the IP observed will not match your home IP (as long as the conversion IP routing table is not available).

So in short rather than connecting directly from `A -> C`, as `C` only trusts `B`, you connect through the proxy `B`: `A -> B -> C`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try WMS Downloader (http://geotrix.eu/) software, a tool that allows you to connect to Web Map Services (WMS) and download georeferenced map tiles to your local drive for future off-line use. It is available as the ArcGIS Addin as well as a standalone Windows app.

The newest release allows to set different proxy settings (i.e. "NO PROXY" or "SYSTEM PROXY").

Disclaimer: I'm one of the coauthors of this tool and this is a licensed product. Feel free to check the trial version. If you would like to see it in action - have a look at [video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtjtGxELdYVqWo6U-d7n25A/videos) on YouTube.